# Strange template error: expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a bizarre error with templating. It's very simple code, but it's throwing two errors. What's wrong with it?

The error:

```
node.h|3|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
node.cpp|3|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

Header file:

```
#pragma once

<template typename T>
class Node
{
    public:
        Node(T data);
        T data;
        Node * next;
};

#include "node.cpp"
```

Implementation file:

```
#include "node.h"

<template typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T nd) : data(nd), next(NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: It's extremely strange and not recommended including the `.cpp` in the `.hpp`, normally is the other way around. You should probably read some tutorial of "C++ (C++11 of course)"

Comment: Second the recommendation that a good tutorial is in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are `template <typename T>`. The `<` goes *after* the `template` keyword.

Comment: I got this same error. Read this solution and was like "oh that's so silly I'd never do that..... oops" Thanks for this!